# How to specify framework version?

Tags: .net, appdomain

How can I specify which .NET framework version to use when I create a new `AppDomain`?

Comment: Do you mean CLR version> (1, 2, 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

All AppDomains run in the same CLR instance.